# Specific listView with Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

How can i make a `listView` like the picture on the post ?
I don't want to use external library, I want to replicate this `Flat Effect`, with spaces between the items.

[image: Listview]

Comment: You can use Your own CustomAdapter to populate data in your ListView. In this CustomAdapter you use your layout file to show data in your required dimension.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Make sure your list item doesn't display dividers (setDividerHeight(0)), then design each cell to have this effect - the white part in the center, with a grey background around it. The white part should probably be a 9patch image to handle the rounded corners and the shadow on the bottom.

Comment: @Ricoxor , have you implemented any adapter for that???

Answer (score 1):

There are few steps to implement this view without using third party library.

1) Make one xml file in `drawable` folder for make this type of view named `layer_card_background.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
 </item>

</layer-list>
```

2) If you wanna a implement change background after select on list items then you also need to make another xml file in `drawable` folder named `layer_card_background_selected.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

3) Make final result xml file in which your both xml file will be included for selector named `selector_card_background.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_card_background_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_card_background"/>

 </selector>
```

4) Make your own custom adapter and apply background for layout

```
  android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
```